# How to place a response xml in active MQ response queue using JMS

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a telecom system which interacts with various third party applications to fetch information like address,payment history etc...Third party systems send response as xmls and that will be generated in one of the queues in Apache Active MQ. Since we are in development phase we do not have the connectivity established to external interfaces. In order to test the application,we simulate the response from third party systems by placing xmls files in respective queues using 'Send to' option in the MQ console before starting the testing

Now i am looking to automate the way we place xmls in active MQ using java jms.Can some one provide me a sample code to start off with?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How should I implement request response with JMS?](http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html) for a description on how to do this. It contains a full example.